# How can I combine torque and html, like ncbi blast service?

Tags: http, web, pbs, torque

I use php to submitted a job to torque (pbs), and it(torque) generate output as:
"This account is currently not available."

I think it reference to account which runs httpd(apache)
apache is a "/sbin/nologin" account

**All I want is to make a html which can submit jobs to pbs and get the result.**
Is this method wrong, I didn't found other solution(may be I don't know which keyword to google).

Thanks for help

I found a solution here:
http://geertvandeweyer.zymichost.com/index.php?page=read&id=9

During debug phrase, setenforce 0, setenforce 1 may help debugging (some time audit.log update slow, need do "setenforce 0;setenforce 1;")
setsebool -P allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam 1        may help

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MAUI witch Torque, you can configure users with different permissions (in maui.cfg).

You can define:

ADMIN1 - users listed under the parameter ADMIN1 are allowed to perform any scheduling function. They have full control over the scheduler and access to all data.

ADMIN2 - users listed under the parameter ADMIN2 are allowed to change all job attributes and are granted access to all informational Maui commands.   Valid values include user names or the keyword 'ALL'.

ADMIN3 - users listed under the parameter ADMIN3 are allowed access to all informational maui commands.  They cannot change scheduler or job attributes.   Valid values include user names or the keyword 'ALL'.

http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/resources/docs/maui/a.esecurity.php